# Is the topology defined here on $C_p(X)$ correct?

Tags: general-topology

The space $X$ is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ where the basis sets for the topology are:
$U = \{ (x,(a,b)) \}$ as described in the picture below: [image]
(is this the space $X=C_p(\mathbb R)$ with the point open topology?)

My question is, what is the topology on the space $C_p(X)$?
Can I view it as the space $X \times \mathbb R$ with basis open sets of the form: $(x,(a,b))$ where $x \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ and $(a,b)$ is an open segment in $\mathbb R$?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: The set $U$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^X$. Perhaps you mean $U(x,(a,b))=\{f:X\to\Bbb R\mid f(x)\in(a,b)\}$. These sets, for all $x\in X, a<b\in\Bbb R$ form a subbase for the product topology on $\Bbb R^X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a topological space $Z$, $C_p ( Z )$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^Z$ (topological product with $\mathbb{R}$ taken as the usual real line) consisting of all continuous functions $f: Z \to \mathbb{R}$.  A sub-basis for $\mathbb{R}^Z$ consists of all sets of the form $$V_{z,(a,b)} = \{ f \in \mathbb{R}^Z : f(z) \in (a,b) \},$$
where $z \in Z$ and $a < b$ are reals; that is, $V_{z,(a,b)}$ is the family of all functions $f : Z \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z)$ lies in the open interval $(a,b)$.

The picture you draw seems to indicate that you are taking the [topological sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_%28topology%29) of $\mathbb{R}$-many copies of the real line (where the underlying set of the space is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$).